# Disable WooCommerce API authentication for Custom endpoint

Tags: wordpress, restful-authentication, woocommerce-rest-api

I have created a custom WooCommerce API endpoint (in a custom WP plugin) for that creates a new order in WooCommerce. I usually use HTTPS and basic auth with consumer key and consumer secret.

This customer API was designed to be accessed by another platform that does not have the ability to enter consumer key and secret in request header. So I would like to disable WooCommerce authentication for this plugin only. I will be authenticating using a field in the original request by comparing a key.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
// To disable authentication, hook into this filter at a later priority and return a valid WP_User

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_api_check_authentication', array( $this, 'authenticate' ), 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment below lines in file woocommerce/includes/class-wc-rest-authentication.php

```
    if ( !hash_equals( $signature, $consumer_signature ) ) { @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
    return new WP_Error( 'woocommerce_rest_authentication_error', __( 'Invalid signature - provided signature does not matchh.', 'woocommerce' ), array( 'status' => 401 ) );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to disable authentication for v3, then disable line 152, 153 in plugins/woocommerce/incoudes/api/legacy/v3/class-wc-api-authentication.php

```
//$this->check_oauth_signature( $keys, $params );
//$this->check_oauth_timestamp_and_nonce( $keys, $params['oauth_timestamp'], $params['oauth_nonce'] );
```